# Check if date is in given format with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, date, datetime-format

How can I check if date is in given format or not. It must be function like this

```
function isInGivenFormat(date,format)
{
//some checking
}
```

For example, `isInGivenFormat("12:45:02","hh:mm:ss")` must return true and `isInGivenFormat("12:45:02 PM","hh:mm:ss")` must return false.
How can I achive this functionality with Javascript/Jquery?

Comment: Oh my god its chuck norris asking a question on Stackoverflow :D Chuck Norris does not ask questions on Stackoverflow, Stackoverflow is asking him questions :D

Comment: :DDDDD Only Jon Skeet can answer on Chuck Norris's question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Date.parseExact()](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation#parseExact) function of the [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) library

Answer (score 4):

```
var dateCheck = /^\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}$/.test(date)
if(!dateCheck){
//not a match
}
```

Comment: +1 But seriously, why would anyone want to use a simple expression when they can get users to load a library instead? :-/ I think it would be better though as `/^\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}$/.test(dateString)`, which is less to type that the accepted library call.

Comment: Yes, this is nice solution for "hh:mm:ss" format, but question is about having generic function for all format versions.
In that case, date.js is more smart solution.

Comment: At RobG. Test is also more appropriate there. It only took me 5 years to notice. Edited  : )

Answer (score 4):

I would urge you to look at the Date.js library. It handles this scenario (and much more).

In particular the [`parseExact()`](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation#parseExact) method solves this problem.

```
Date.parseExact ( String dateString, String formatStringOrArray ) : Date
```

Converts the specified string value into its JavaScript Date equivalent using the specified format (string) or formats (array). The format of the string value must match one of the supplied formats exactly.

**Examples**

```
Date.parseExact("12:45:02 PM","hh:mm:ss"); // returns null
Date.parseExact("10/15/2004", "M/d/yyyy");  // The Date of 15-Oct-2
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the regular expressions. This link could help:

[regex in javascript](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html)

Comment: How can I use regular expressions when format can be everything?

Comment: create a regular expression for each format you want to use, or create a function which analizes your formats to create a regular expresion dynamically.

Comment: Or just do this: var formats = {}; format['hh:mm:ss'] = //regex

Comment: in which way is that different from creating a regex for each format?